# Fail message during boot. Can I delay boot or how do I solve it?

Tags: boot, dmesg

I have a red boot message with error during boot, but I cant figure out what is it. I can see it says FAIL and thats all, It boots too fast ;)

I have tried to look in syslog and dmesg | grep fail/error but I can't find anything major. Am I missing something?

dmesg | grep fail

> [    0.347271] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC failed (AE_SUPPORT); disabling
>   ASPM
>
> [    2.091914] ata4.00: READ LOG DMA EXT failed, trying unqueued
>
> [    2.092420] ata4.00: failed to get NCQ Send/Recv Log Emask 0x1
>
> [    2.096434] ata4.00: failed to get NCQ Send/Recv Log Emask 0x1
>
> [    2.938954] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for
>   iwlwifi-7265D-15.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    2.939112] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for
>   iwlwifi-7265D-14.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    4.902991] vmmon: module verification failed: signature and/or
>   required key missing - tainting kernel

dmesg | grep error:

> [    2.738863] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
>
> [    2.938954] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for
>   iwlwifi-7265D-15.ucode failed with error -2
>
> [    2.939112] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for
>   iwlwifi-7265D-14.ucode failed with error -2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I got some help from reddit, and I figured I would share it here.

The file is: /var/log/boot.log